# I need a jQuery plugin to write with a light pen

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

I need a plugin for my project. A jQuery plugin that I can write with a light pen. I need to set the font size and change the color of the pen. Is there a plugin for this purpose?
Thank You so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest these plugins:

[jScribble](https://github.com/jimdoescode/jqScribble)
[wPaint](https://github.com/websanova/wPaint)